# Doctrine query builder based on array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to doctrine 2 and just wondering, if there is something similar to the options parameter in fuelphp ORM. Something like this:

```
$options = array(
    "limit" => 10,
    "offset" => 10,
    "and_where" => array(
        array("id", "=", 1),
        array("price", ">", 10)
    )
);

...
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder();
$query->addOptions($options);
...
```

Comment: I suggest you read Doctrine docs

Comment: I have read it, but I didn't found something similar. Since I wasn't sure, if I searched for the right terms, I just asekd, if there is something similar. A simple no, or "I have no idea", would be enoght.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php
    $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $queryBuilder->andWhere("a.price = :price")
        ->setParameter('price', 10);
    $queryBuilder->setMaxResults(100); // limit
    $queryBuilder->setFirstResult(0); // offset

    // for complicated condition, use the query builder expression
    $expr = $queryBuilder->expr();
    $queryBuilder->andWhere(
        $expr->gte("a.price", ':price')
    )->setParameter('price', 10);
?>
```

You can see all the expression methods inside this class `Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr`